# Unexpected tag names in WCF Service Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a wcf service and I have class like below:

```
public class Message
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "message")]
    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    public string message { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MsgID")]
    [DataMember(Name = "MsgID")]
    public string MsgID{ get; set; }
}
```

Then i browsed my service in a browser the XML i am getting like below:

```
<MessageResponse>
    <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
    <Messages>
       <a:Message>
         <a:message>msg1</a:message>
         <a:MsgID>1</a:MsgID>
       </a:Message>
    </Messages>
</MessageResponse>
```

My Service Contract is Like below: and one more important thing is:
**MessageDco class is a copy of Message Class**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="")] 
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]    
    public class UserLoginProfileService
    {        
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetMessages?MsgID={MsgID}")]
        public MessageResponse GetMessage(Guid MsgID)
        {
            MessageResponse objMessageResponse = new MessageResponse();
            try
            {

                Message[] objMessage = new MessageFacade().GetMessage(MsgIDs);
                if (objUserLoginProfile != null)
                {
                    MessageResponse.Status = Status.Success;                   
                    MessageResponse.Messages =Mapper.ToDataContractObjects(objMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    objMessageResponse.Status = Status.Success;                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                objMessageResponse.Status = Status.Failure;               

            }
            return objMessageResponse;
        }
    }

public class MessageResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Messages")]
          [DataMember(Name = "Messages")]
        public MessageDco[] Messages { get; set; }

          [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
          [DataMember(Name = "Status")]
          public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

My mapper class is like below:

```
public sealed class Mapper
    {
     public static MessageDco[] ToDataContractObjects(IEnumerable<MessageDco> objMessageDco)
    {
        if (objMessageDco != null)
        {
            return objMessageDco.Select(a => ToDataContractObjects(a)).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

if we see "a:" is added to the tags. why it is added? i am unable remove that "a:" from the tags. Please help me how to remove "a:" from Tags. And also if you see MessageResponse class (Status tag) is coming correct But array list(i.e: Message[]) in MessageResponse is Coming wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` is a generated namespace for your elements.

For the DataContractSerializer you can remove the namespace for your types in your service definition using the `ServiceContractAttribute` like so:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rich. I edited Response XML, This is the correct XML which i was getting from the Service. I added name space to the ServiceContract(Like:[ServiceContract(Namespace="")] ) But the response was same. Please tell me if i am doing any thing wrong in my code.